# My spotlights are making weird shape reflections on glass

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light, effects

I am a Blender beginner and I'm trying to create an interior scene for my exam, but at this moment my lights create a weird reflection effect on the glass.

I imported a spotlight from an .obj file and assigned a PBR metal to the mesh and an Emission Node to the central surface of the spotlight for the light.

I realized it was to weak to light up my scene so I also added a Blender spot. It's probably not the way I should do it, but that's the only one I know to avoid fireflies and get a good result, although on the glass my lights are creating a weird hemisphere reflection, really bright and with sharp edge.

I set the bounces to 1 to check if it was a reflection problem or not and that's the result.

Could you please help me, what did I do wrong? Thank you so much.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advise getting rid o additional duplicate lamps overlapping in one spot, if one is not enough to light your scene up increase its strength.

Having double lamps overlapping is redundant and will likely lead to issues, besides the obvious performance issues. Having multiple lamps realistically distributed across your scene is of course ok and encouraged.

Anyway, you are most likely using either *Area* or *Point* lights, not spots, these are never visible in reflections, as far as I know.

Try disabling the Lamp object visibility to Cycles *Glossy* component.

[image: Cycles Glossy]

Alternatively use a node setup in your lamp with a [*Light Path* node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/light_paths.html) limiting it's visibility to glossy components.

Comment: Thank you for this!